# Big-O of list comprehension that calls max in the condition: O(n) or O(n^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, big-o, list-comprehension

Q. Write an algorithm that returns the second largest number in an array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(max([x for x in a if x != max(a)]))
>> 4
```

I'm trying to figure out how this algorithm works and whether or not pythons internal magic will make this as efficient as writing a linear algorithm which just loops over the list `a` once and stores the highest and second highest values.

Correct me if I'm wrong:

- The call to `max(a)` would be O(n)
- `[x for x in a]` would also be O(n)

Would python be smart enough to cache the value of `max(a)` or would this mean that the list comprehension part the algorithm is O(n^2)?

And then the final `max([listcomp])` would be another O(n), but this would only run once after the comprehension is finished, so the final algorithm would be O(n^2)?

Is there any fancy business going on internally that would cache the `max(a)` value and result in this algorithm working out quicker than O(n^2)?

Comment: How about a bit of benchmarking?

Comment: It's `O(n**2)` because python doesn't cache the result of `max` ... and that's important because `a` could've changed! I'm not sure the algorithm is even correct. I mean if the list is `[1,3,3]` I would expect the "function" to give me `3` because it's the largest and second largest number. But your function gives `1`.

Comment: You should [edit] your question title. You've posted an assignment question as the sole title, and you're going to attract downvotes because of it. In addition, that title has no relevance to the question you're actually asking here, and will have no value as written to future readers seeing it in a search result.

Comment: Feel free to help out with the title..........

Comment: I think expecting python to optimize O(n^2) down to O(n) is roughly equivalent to shooting yourself in the foot. There are faster and more readable ways to write this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way to find out is timing it. Consider this timing code:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    a = list(range(10**i))
    %timeit max([x for x in a if x != max(a)])
```

```
17.6 µs ± 178 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
698 µs ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
61.6 ms ± 340 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
6.31 s ± 167 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Each time it multiplied the number of elements by 10 the runtime increased by 100. That's almost certainly `O(n**2)`. For an `O(n)` algorithm the runtime would increase linearly with the number of elements:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    a = list(range(10**i))
    max_ = max(a)
    %timeit max([x for x in a if x != max_])
```

```
4.82 µs ± 27.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
29 µs ± 161 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
262 µs ± 3.89 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.42 ms ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
24.9 ms ± 231 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

But I'm not certain the algorithm really does what is asked. Consider the list `a=[1,3,3]` even the `heapq` module tells me that the second largest element is `3` (not 1 - what your algorithm returns):

```
import heapq

>>> heapq.nlargest(2, [1,3,3])[0]
3
```

Comment: Interesting. It would seem "second largest" needs some deeper thinking to its definition.

Comment: Would the heapq algorithm be O(n)? I've only come across this module today and have seen it twice so far in regards to performance questions

Comment: @AK47: `heapq` would be `O(n log k)`, where `n` is the length of the input, and `k` is the number of elements to find; it has higher constant factors than `sorted`, so in general, you want `k` to be smallish (if it's anywhere near half the size of the input, odds are a complete `sorted` run will be faster). Basically, it just maintains a heap of size `k`, with each new element (in theory) requiring up to `log k` work to handle (if it needs to do a `heapreplace` operations). When it finishes consuming the input, it does `O(k log k)` work to sort the resulting heap, then returns it.

Answer (score 3):

> Would python be smart enough to cache the value of max(a) or would
>   this mean that the list comprehension part the algorithm is `O(n^2)`?

No, because, as MSeifert said in a comment, python doesn't make assumptions about `a`, and so doesn't cache the value of `max(a)`, which is recomputed each time.

You might want to consider an implementation that keeps track of the largest two items in one pass. You'll need to code an explicit `for` loop and do it. Here's a useful link from [`GeeksForGeeks`](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-second-largest-element-array/) (this, I recommend).

Alternatively, you can consider multiple traversals that still ends up being linear in complexity.

```
In [1782]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [1783]: max(set(a) - {max(a)}) # 3 linear traversals
Out[1783]: 4
```

There's scope for improvement here, but like I said, nothing beats the explicit `for` loop approach.

Comment: In CPython, multiple runs using minimal python code and letting builtins do most of the work (e.g. your solution) is probably going to be much better than a fancy but long algorithm.

Comment: I'll definitely check out that link you provided. Trying to get used to calculating the time complexity of the code I'm writing so having both of your implementations definitely help, especially in comparison to the original code I've written